# How can I get the pop up window on ListView which accept number

Tags: android, listview

Actually I have created a list in which on each menu of list I want to get a **pop up window in which I can give the quantity (Number of pieces).** And **after click the list content should be ticked and It must show quantity with tick mark.**

Here is my code of **OnItemClickListener** ListView :

```
         list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                click = arg2;
                clickstr = (String) ((TextView)arg1).getText(); 

              final CharSequence[] items = { "Mango", "Banana", "Apple" };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenus.this);
                builder.setTitle("Enter the quantity");

                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {     
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        list1.setItemChecked(click, true);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You click "+ clickstr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This program shows a AlertDialog box with the Items. BUT I dont want this **I want a window which will accept number and that item should get ticked and show the number we put there.**

Thank you.

Comment: try custom dialog from here [Android Dialogs](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-dialogs-tutorial-for-begginer.html)

Comment: @Ketan Your post is really good and appreciable but I want the popup window which would accept a numeric value not showing menus.

Comment: in dialog you can add custom view with edittext that will accept number.

Comment: You mean to say I should have to take new .xml which will have edittext and that xml will be called on click on list. Right?

Do you have any simple example? @ketan

Comment: have look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one xml **res/layout/my_layout.xml** wiht `Button` and `EditText` then use below code

```
final View mylayout=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayot,null);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(mylayout);
            Button btn=(Button)mylayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final EditText edit=(EditText)mylayout.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text=edit.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You click "+ text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: I am trying to do this but it is not allowing me to take `Dialog.setContentView(mylayout);`
**Error is** `01-08 06:34:23.972: E/AndroidRuntime(2974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 06:34:23.972: E/AndroidRuntime(2974): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 06:34:23.972: E/AndroidRuntime(2974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3338)
01-08 06:34:23.972: E/AndroidRuntime(2974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
01-08 06:34:23.972: E/AndroidRuntime(2974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3186)
`
@ketan

Comment: Hello Ketan Have you done what I told you yesterday. Please come there on chat. @Ketan